# What is the meaning of "testifies to"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Within a mere two centuries we have become alienated individuals. **Nothing testifies better to the awesome power of culture.**

The last sentence doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Testify to" means "provide evidence for". You *testify* (give evidence) in a court of law. The author is commenting on the power of our technological culture to alienate us by driving us physically and emotionally apart. He seems to think that this trend started with the industrial revolution, two centuries ago.

[Cambridge Dictionary: Testify](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/testify)